# Custom OCHamcrest matcher for OCMockito mock verfication

Tags: ios, unit-testing, tdd, ocmockito, ochamcrest

I am using OCHamcrest and OCMockito for unit testing an iOS project.  I'm working my way toward understanding using custom matchers in a mock verification of a method expectation that takes parameters.  In particular, I want to verify one of the parameters passed to the expected method, but I need to pull apart the passed parameter in order to do so.  To demonstrate, here's what I have for the relevant part of my test method:

```
EAAccessory *accessory = mock([EAAccessory class]);
UIViewController <ZKSearchManagerDelegate> *mockController = 
    mockObjectAndProtocol(
        [UIViewController class], @protocol(ZKSearchManagerDelegate)
    );
[verify(mockController) 
        zkZSensorFound:isSensorWithAccessory(accessory) 
     fromSearchManager:_sm];
```

The `-zkZSensorFound:fromSearchManager:` takes an object that contains an `EAAccessory` as a property.  In my custom matcher, I need to open up that object and examine that property to make sure it's the same object as `accessory` within this test method.  It's easy enough to pass `accessory` into the matcher as I'm doing here, but how do I get at the actual object that is passed to the parameter for use inside of my matcher?  Or, am I going about this all wrong?

#### Update

I've accepted the answer from @JonReid, as it's a much more elegant solution than what I've concocted.  Nevertheless, I think what I was using (thanks to [this](http://hataewon.tumblr.com/post/24767032790/argument-captor-for-objective-c) blog post), could be useful elsewhere:

```
#import "ArgumentCaptor.h"

EAAccessory *accessory = mock([EAAccessory class]);
UIViewController <ZKSearchManagerDelegate> *mockController = 
    mockObjectAndProtocol(
        [UIViewController class], @protocol(ZKSearchManagerDelegate)
    );
ArgumentCaptor *captor = argCaptor();
[verify(_mockController) zkZSensorFound:(ZKZSensor *)captor 
                      fromSearchManager:is(sameInstance(_sm))];
ZKZSensor *sensor = captor.argument;
assertThat(sensor.accessory, is(_mockAccessory));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, be aware that when you don't specify a matcher to OCMockito, it uses the `isEqual` matcher. This probably isn't what you want to verify for the second argument. I'd check for identity instead:

```
fromSearchManager:sameInstance(_sm)
```

If the argument is typed, it will complain that the matcher `sameInstance` isn't a search manager. The workaround is to cast the matcher to remove the typing:

```
fromSearchManager:(id)sameInstance(_sm)
```

Now for the first argument: you may not need to make a custom matcher at all. If all you want to do is check a property value, use `hasProperty`. Assuming the property is named `accessory`,

```
zkZSensorFound:(id)hasProperty(@"accessory", sameInstance(accessory))
```

Putting it all together:

```
[verify(mockController) 
        zkZSensorFound:(id)hasProperty(@"accessory", sameInstance(accessory)) 
     fromSearchManager:(id)sameInstance(_sm)];
```